# Publishing Asp.Net Core to IIS 7.5 LocalDb Error (Development Mode)

Tags: asp.net-core, localdb, access-denied

I have published an asp.net core 2.0 web application on IIS 7.5, which is working fine if stick to the home page. 
When we want to access the database, it shows this error

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvzsw.png)

I've also done this but still error remains there,
"   "

Database: LocalDB

Also configured application pool as local db but still issues remains there.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you are having this issue. Could you be kind enough to share a detailed exception like you did with the error page you shared above? If you can. It will help in resolving this issue quickly.

More so, you might want to do the following:

- Make sure you have the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle installed. Which I think you have done, because your app runs and shows the home page.
- So, add the IIS app pool for your application as DB Login, with the DB
  Owner privilege.
- Check the DB Connection string for the environment which you are deploying for. In this case I believe its not Development.

In your Startup.cs file do this as well.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if(env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
  }
}
```

This should help show you more detailed error. Also, try this if it doesn't work

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, create a new user in Security -> Logins (in the same nesting level as the 'Databases' folder). User must have name like your application pool in IIS Server. Give it the DB Owner permission like I suggested above.

I hope this helps, kindly let me know if it does in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the environment virable **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** and set its value to **Development** than we can tell what is your exact exception message.

Besides, what is your DataBase? SQL Server, MySql.

If you are using sql database and your connection string specifies login as sql user, please make sure your application pool are using  that user to connect database